# Почему я не могу получить ip адреса при запуске сканера на scapy

Tags: python, tcp, localhost, scanner, scapy

при запуске кода

```
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from scapy.layers.l2 import ARP
from scapy.layers.l2 import srp
from scapy.packet import ls



def send_in_local_host(ip):
    arp_packet = ARP(pdst=ip)
    brodcast = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    arp_packet_brodcast = brodcast / arp_packet
    answered, unananswered = srp(arp_packet_brodcast, timeout=1)
    print(answered.summary())


send_in_local_host()
```

я получаю это

```
   Begin emission:
Finished sending 256 packets.
.
Received 1 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 256 packets
None
```

хотя устройства в сети есть

что я делаю не так?
как это исправить?

Comment: время ожидания слишком мало (иногда я видел проблемы с тайм-аутом 2 с и переходом на 5 помогало)
Ваш брандмауэр (ОС или маршрутизатор) может блокировать этот трафик
IP-адрес, который вы используете, srcневерен (вы можете проверить это ifconfigв Linux и ipconfigWindows)

Comment: Я поставил число 5 в timeout и всё получилось спасибо большое!!!